# Most succinct setup for developing and buiding a ReactJS application

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Apparently all environments for developing and building a ReactJS app consist of:

```
"babel-core": "^6.3.26",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
"react": "^0.14.3",
"react-dom": "^0.14.3",
"react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",  // optional
"webpack": "^1.12.9",
```

What exactly is the role of Babel in this setup? Is there anything it does that Webpack cannot do? Does it have to be part of the environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your question refers to `babel-core` - "why do I need `babel-core` when I have `babel-loader` for webpack?"

The rold of `babel-loader` is obvious - `babel-loader` transpiles ES6 js/jsx to ES5 using the presets. In addition, webpack 1 doesn't support ES6 modules without `babel-loader`.

The `babel-loader` requires as a peer dependency `babel-core`. According to the [NPM blog](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/110924823920/npm-weekly-5), NPM 3 doesn't install peer-dependency automatically, and they need to be installed separately.

> We will also be changing the behavior of peerDependencies in npm@3. We
>   won’t be automatically downloading the peer dependency anymore.
>   Instead, we’ll warn you if the peer dependency isn’t already
>   installed. This requires you to resolve peerDependency conflicts
>   yourself, manually, but in the long run this should make it less
>   likely that you’ll end up in a tricky spot with your packages’
>   dependencies.

That's why you also need to include `babel-core` in your `package.json`.

Comment: What intrigued me was reading a post where a developer used `jsx-loader` - so it got me started to think `babel` (en gross) was not needed anymore.

Comment: The nice thing is that [jsx-loader github page](https://github.com/petehunt/jsx-loader) readme.md states: "don't use this! use babel-loader instead." :)